# How do you post data to a server using Core Data and AFIncrementalStore?

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking

I've just started using the awesome [**AFIncrementalStore**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore) and have managed to get a basic iOS app running that displays data from a server (JSON format) displayed in a UITableView.

But how can I post data to the same (RESTful) server? Just creating a new `NSManagedObject` instance and saving properties to it saves data to the local Core Data store, but nothing is posted to the server.

The [AFIncrementalStore ReadMe](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore) mentions "POST to server" in the "Next Steps" section, but someone maybe has managed to figure out a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku now has a tutorial on using AFIncrementalStore and Core Data Buildpack to build a to-do application, including listing and posting new data:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app

Answer (score 3):

If it's listed under "Next Steps", and nobody has submitted a Pull Request containing an implementation, then it is pretty likely that nobody has implemented it yet. So, your options are:

1. Read the NSIncrementalStore documentation and update the AFIncrementalStore code to support POST-to-server, or
2. Wait for somebody else to do it.